# Excel VBA Formula not working in German excel

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I dont know why this formula is not working. Any help (german version of excel 2007)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)    
Dim Calc As Double    
Calc = 1.5    
Range("A2").Formula = "= B2 *C2 * & Calc & "    
End Sub
```

I want to use formula . without .formula it works.

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't work under English locale, too. `* &` is not a valid sequence of operators.

My psychic powers tell me you want to embed `Calc` into the formula as a literal, in which case it should be

```
Range("A2").Formula = "= B2 *C2 * " & Str$(Calc)
```

You have to use `Str` to have `Calc` converted into a string according to the English locale, required by `Formula`. You could leave it as is if using `FormulaLocal`.